how to fix this issue: export 'GlobalStyle'.'fadeIn' (imported as 'GlobalStyle') was not found in '../../style' (possible exports: default)
I ran into an error message which was working fine till today. and Here is the error message I am facing. i am using node@16.13.0 and npm@8.1.0.
I changes the node versions and still facing the same issue. Below is the error messages I am getting while running the npm run start.
ERROR in ./src/components/AlertModal/AlertModal.tsx 32:19-37
export 'GlobalStyle'.'fadeIn' (imported as 'GlobalStyle') was not found in '../../style' (possible exports: default)

ERROR in ./src/components/AlertModal/AlertModal.tsx 39:19-38
export 'GlobalStyle'.'flexRow' (imported as 'GlobalStyle') was not found in '../../style' (possible exports: default)

globalstyle.module.scss
 @import '../assets/css/variables.scss';
    
    // Import this file as a module: Do not import as a side effect
    :root {
      --ct-blue: rgba(11, 11, 54, 0.87);
      --color-dark-blue: var(--ct-blue);
      --color-gray-blue-0: #505b7b;
      --color-gray-blue-1: #232f50;
    }
    
    .fadeIn {
      animation: fadeIn ease-in-out 300ms;
      @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {
          transform: translateY(-8px);
          opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
          transform: translateY(0);
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }

globalStyle.module.scss.d
export const fadeIn: string;
    export const fadeInSimple: string;
    export const flatCard: string;
    export const flatCardContainer: string;

index.ts
export * as GlobalStyle from './globalStyle.module.scss';

AlertModal.tsx
 import { Button, ButtonProps } from '../../containers/Application/components/button';
    import { GlobalStyle } from '../../style';
    
    export type AlertModalProps = {
      title: string;
      message: string;
      display: boolean;
      footerButtons?: ButtonProps[];
      dismissModal?: () => void;
    };
    
    export function AlertModal(props: AlertModalProps) {
      return (
        <div
          style={props.display ? {} : { display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}
          className="ui-modal-container"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            props.dismissModal && props.dismissModal();
          }}>
          <div
            className="ui-modal-dialog"
            onClick={(ev) => {
              ev.stopPropagation();
            }}>
            <header>{props.title}</header>
            {props.message && <p className={GlobalStyle.fadeIn}>{props.message}</p>}
            <footer className={GlobalStyle.flexRow}>
              {props.footerButtons?.map((props, i) => (
                <Button key={i} {...props} />
              ))}
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }


